# Not using actionbar; Failed to load AppCompat ActionBar with unknown error

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Can't seem to find anything related to this. Code does not contain anything to do with actionbar, but preview and design are getting render errors due to it. Any ideas?

If you need more information (code, or other) let me know and I'll update what is needed.

I feel like this is a new user type of question..

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using AppCompat for anything else?
Have you tried a full clean,restart, rebuild?

Comment: I'm using a LinearLayout for everything. Each layout has custom touch events. I don't believe I am unless the AppCompat is there for compatibility for lower versions. Clean Yes, Restart Android Studio, Rebuild Yes

Comment: Can you do a Ctrl + F search entire project for "ActionBar" and see if you get any results?

Comment: Not sure what changed; Maybe updating. The issue is gone as suddenly as it came. I think maybe gradle may have had some issue that updating resolved. But no there were no ActionBar items in the entire project

Answer (score 1):

Check whether you use styles-v7.xml or other theme.

Search all `import android.support.v7`

Check all your files named *-v7 or AppCompat

AppCompat is not only in ActionBar, but also in AppCompatActivity and some themes.